# Puppet - OSX NFS mount refreshing and triggering remount

Tags: macos, puppet, osx-yosemite, mount, nfs

I've been fighting with this for a while, and I've narrowed it down to a test puppet manifest which illustrates the problem.

Basically, I'm defining the File resource, then defining a Mount resources to mount an NFS share in that directory. However, looking at the debug output, it would appear that the checking of the directory is triggering a "refresh" event, which is in turn causing Puppet to unmount and remount the share. Something in this process causes the directory to be removed, which then causes the remount to fail.

I've checked the /Volumes directory mid-run, before the Mount refresh runs, and it *does* create the directory, so I can only assume it's the `umount` command which removes it.

I've tried it with a `before` dependency on the File resource (shown below) and also using a `require` dependency on the Mount resource, with the same result.

Example Puppet manifest:

```
file { "/Volumes/share":
  ensure => directory,
  before => Mount["/Volumes/share"]
}

mount {"/Volumes/share":
  ensure  => "mounted",
  device  => "xxxx@yyyy.net:/share",
  name    => "/Volumes/share",
  atboot  => true,
  fstype  => "nfs",
  options => "",
}
```

And here's the `--debug` output:

```
Debug: Loaded state in 0.02 seconds
Debug: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/Volumes/share]/before: requires Mount[/Volumes/share]
Info: Applying configuration version '1429802875'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/Volumes/share]/ensure: created
Debug: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/Volumes/share]: The container Class[Main] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Prefetching parsed resources for mount
Debug: Executing '/sbin/mount'
Debug: Flushing mount provider target /etc/fstab
Info: Computing checksum on file /etc/fstab
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Mount[/Volumes/share]/ensure: ensure changed 'unmounted' to 'mounted'
Debug: Executing '/sbin/mount -o  /Volumes/share'
Debug: /Stage[main]/Main/Mount[/Volumes/share]: The container Class[Main] will propagate my refresh event
Info: /Stage[main]/Main/Mount[/Volumes/share]: Scheduling refresh of Mount[/Volumes/share]
Info: Mount[/Volumes/share](provider=parsed): Remounting
Debug: Executing '/sbin/umount /Volumes/share'
Debug: Executing '/sbin/mount -o  /Volumes/share'
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Mount[/Volumes/share]: Failed to call refresh: Execution of '/sbin/mount -o  /Volumes/share' returned 1: mount: realpath /Volumes/share: No such file or directory
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Mount[/Volumes/share]: Execution of '/sbin/mount -o  /Volumes/share' returned 1: mount: realpath /Volumes/share: No such file or directory
Debug: Class[Main]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
Debug: Finishing transaction 70139321047620
Debug: Storing state
Debug: Stored state in 0.11 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.70 seconds
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rrddir': 'File[/var/lib/puppet/rrd]{:path=>"/var/lib/puppet/rrd", :mode=>"750", :owner=>"root", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Finishing transaction 70139327177180
Debug: Received report to process from zzzz.yyyy.net
Debug: Processing report from zzzz.yyyy.net with processor Puppet::Reports::Store
```

Edit:

I've found that one of the hosts which was failing just started working, as if by magic. I've collected the reports around which it started working:

```
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]   Failed to call refresh: Execution of '/sbin/mount -o /Volumes/share' returned 1: mount: realpath /Volumes/share: No such file or directory
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]   Execution of '/sbin/mount -o /Volumes/share' returned 1: mount: realpath /Volumes/share: No such file or directory
```

Then (later):

```
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]   Could not evaluate: Execution of '/sbin/mount -o /Volumes/share' returned 61: mount_nfs: warning: option "0" not known mount_nfs: can't mount /share from zzzz.yyyy.net onto /Volumes/share: Connection refused
```

One more failure, later again:

```
//aaaa.yyyy.net/Puppet  Failed to set owner to '501': No such file or directory - /Volumes/share
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/File[/Volumes/share]/owner  change from root to administrator failed: Failed to set owner to '501': No such file or directory - /Volumes/share
//aaaa.yyyy.net/Puppet  Failed to set group to '21': No such file or directory - /Volumes/share
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/File[/Volumes/share]/group  change from wheel to administrator failed: Failed to set group to '21': No such file or directory - /Volumes/share
//aaaa.yyyy.net/Puppet  failed to set mode 555 on /Volumes/share: No such file or directory - /Volumes/share
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/File[/Volumes/share]/mode   change from 0555 to 0777 failed: failed to set mode 555 on /Volumes/share: No such file or directory - /Volumes/share
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]   Dependency File[/Volumes/share] has failures: true
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]   Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

And finally:

```
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/File[/Volumes/share]/owner  owner changed 'root' to 'administrator'
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/File[/Volumes/share]/group  group changed 'wheel' to 'administrator'
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/File[/Volumes/share]/mode   mode changed '0555' to '0777'
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]/options   options changed '0' to ''
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]/pass  defined 'pass' as '0'
//aaaa.yyyy.net//Stage[main]/Osx-common/Mount[/Volumes/share]   Triggered 'refresh' from 2 events
```

And that's it working. I've no idea why this host is now working properly but the first host is failing as described!

Comment: So this is interesting. It's now working on one of the two machines I am applying the class to.

I'll go back through the reports and see what changed and when.

Comment: I've edited the question with the reports from the working host.

Comment: try to use after in mount resource or resource ordering

Comment: I've already tried using a `require` instead of the `before`, and the situation is identical unfortunately!

Comment: but in the mount resource, have you tried to use "after" options

Comment: The documentation for the current version only shows `require` as being `after`, it doesn't list after as an option. Thanks for the ordering answer, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use puppet ordering arrow.

```
file { "/Volumes/share":
  ensure => directory,
}

mount {"/Volumes/share":
  ensure  => "mounted",
  device  => "xxxx@yyyy.net:/share",
  name    => "/Volumes/share",
  atboot  => true,
  fstype  => "nfs",
  options => "",
}

File["/Volumes/share"] -> Mount["/Volumes/share"]
```

Comment: That *had* done it, until I had to restart the machine on which this started working out-of-the-blue originally (see question). Then it started failing. I'm guessing the thing which made it start working on that machine originally made it work on the original problem machine. I'll try the other ordering examples and see what happens.